# AWS sdk dynamodb scan not working with code but its working in DynamoDb UI of aws console

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

```
   var param = { TableName: 'events-dev', 
FilterExpression: '#user_id = :userid AND #dt BETWEEN :dt AND :dt1',
ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#user_id': 'user_id', '#dt': 'updatedAt'},
ExpressionAttributeValues: {':userid': 'fc0c6610-e17f-444e-887a-e556f9d17853',':dt': '2021-12-01',':dt1': '2021-12-02'}}

dynamoDb.scan(params, (error, data) => {           
if (!error) { 
console.log('data==', data.Items)});
result: []
```

But i got response when search it in the aws console

[image: Result after searching in UI]

Comment: What are you getting as a response in code?

Comment: {
  Items: [],
  Count: 0,
  ScannedCount: 90,
  LastEvaluatedKey: {
    event_id: '426af7d4-dcfa-428c-8dba-63557c9cba77',
    device_id: '06cd6d4c-f16f-411f-8f8a-47deac83f805'
  }
},
got this as response